# How to serialize a parameterized type to JSON in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, aeson

Say you have a simple type, and want to serialize it to JSON with Aeson. Here is the basic setup:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Aeson (ToJSON)
import Data.Aeson (encode)
import GHC.Generics

data Spotting = Spotting {
  state :: String,
  bird :: String
} deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON Spotting
```

Now say you want, in addition to the `bird` and `state` field, to allow users to pass in extra/custom metadata. For a bird spotting, maybe this is the air temperature, the density of birds, the position of the tide... could be anything, we don't know in advance.

From looking at examples like the [Twitter API in Haskell](https://github.com/himura/twitter-types/blob/master/Web/Twitter/Types.hs), it seems like you'd want to structure it like this:

```
data Spotting meta = Spotting {
  state :: String,
  bird :: String,
  meta :: meta
} deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON meta => ToJSON (Spotting meta)
```

From my understanding so far, this is a *parameterized type*. The goal is to now make a simple way of creating some JSON out of that object. So we define a function like this:

```
spotting bird state meta = encode $ Spotting {
  state = state,
  bird = bird,
  meta = meta
}
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here yet. When I call that function like this:

```
record = spotting "Snowy Egret" "California" "low tide"
```

It throws an error (I am new to Haskell so am still learning the basics of how to interpret all of this stuff)

```
No instance for (Data.String.IsString meta0)
  arising from the literal `"low tide"'
The type variable `meta0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Data.String.IsString
             aeson-0.7.0.6:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value
    -- Defined in `aeson-0.7.0.6:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal'
  instance a ~ Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString =>
           Data.String.IsString
             (attoparsec-0.12.1.2:Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Internal.Parser a)
    -- Defined in `Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8'
  instance Data.String.IsString Data.Text.Internal.Text
    -- Defined in `Data.Text'
  ...plus five others
In the third argument of `spotting', namely `"low tide"'
In the expression:
  spotting "Snowy Egret" "California" "low tide"
In an equation for `record':
    record = spotting "Snowy Egret" "California" "low tide"
```

What is happening here / how do you get this to work?

The final goal is, not to pass in a string in the `meta` field, but a typed object (but it can be any object), such as this:

```
record = spotting "Snowy Egret" "California" MyCustomData {
  tide = "low"
}
```

How do you accomplish this in Haskell?

Comment: `Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is because you have OverloadedStrings turned on....

When you type

```
record = spotting "Snowy Egret" "California" "low tide"
```

the compiler needs to determine what type `meta` is.  Because `encode` is capable of parsing many types, it is of no help in telling the compiler what to use.  Without OverloadedStrings, `"low tide"` is clearly of type String, but with it, it could be `String`, `ByteString`, etc.

You have two choices in fixing this....

Either-

Remove OverloadedStrings

or-

Specify the type explicitly.

```
value = "low tide"::String
record = spotting "Snowy Egret" "California" value
```